# How to load string from array based on RNG in MIPS?

Tags: arrays, string, assembly, random, mips

I'm trying to load a random string from an array of strings based on an RNG output in MIPS for a project in my Assembly Class - I'm having a significantly difficult time. The output doesn't make sense. The portion of the code dealing with this is as follows:

```
SEED:
li $v0 30       #get time syscall
syscall

move $a1 $a0
li $a0 1
li $v0 40       #seed RND syscall - a0 RNG ID, a1 Time
syscall

RNG:    
li $a1 10       #upper bound java.util.Random rnd.nexInt(n)
li $v0 42       #get RND syscall - a0 RNG ID, a1 range -> a0 has #
syscall

li $t1 5
mult $a0 $t1
mflo $s1

LOADWORD:
la $s2 bank
add $s2 $s2 $s1     #shift wordbank based on rng
la $s3 word

lb $t0 0($s2)       #1st letter
sb $t1 0($s3)

lb $t1 1($s2)       #2nd letter
sb $t1 1($s3)

lb $t2 2($s2)       #3rd letter
sb $t1 2($s3)

lb $t3 3($s2)       #4th letter
lb $t3 3($s3)

lb $t4 4($s2)       #5th letter
lb $t4 4($s3)

move $a0 $s3
li $v0 4
syscall
```

I believe the problem I'm having has to deal with the tag #shift wordbank based on RNG. Can anyone help me with this? I'm currently using just a large string, as in "HELLOCHAIRWORDSCOUCH..." and just trying to load a five character string from it - is there a better way to do this? Thanks.